# Why is a CNN model struggling to classify a colored MNIST?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, rgb, mnist

I'm trying to classify colored MNIST digits with a basic CNN architecture on Keras. Here is the piece of code that colors the original dataset into purely either red, green or blue.

```py
def load_norm_data():
  ## load basic mnist
  (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
  train_images = np.zeros((*x_train.shape, 3)) # orig shape: (60 000, 28, 28, 1) -> rgb shape: (60 000, 28, 28, 3)
  for num in range(x_train.shape[0]):
    rgb = np.random.randint(3) 
    train_images[num, ..., rgb] = x_train[num]/255
  return train_images, y_train
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  ims, labels = load_norm_data()
  for num in range(10):
    plt.subplot(2, 5, num+1)
    plt.imshow(ims[num])
    plt.axis('off')
```

which gives for the first couple of digits:

[image]

Then, I attempt to classify this colored dataset into the same 10 digit classes of MNIST, so the labels aren't changing --and yet the models accuracy drops from 95% for non-colored MNIST, to wildly variable 30-70% on colored MNIST, vastly depending on weight initialization... Please find below the architecture of said model:

```py
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Softmax())

input_shape = train_images.shape
model.build(input_shape)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(train_images, train_numbers, batch_size=12, epochs=25)
```

Initially, I thought that this drop in performance might be linked to data irregularity (e.g. imagine a lot of 3s in the data ended up being green, thus the model learns green = 3). So I checked the data, the counts are good and the rgb distribution for each class is near 33% for each color too. I also checked the misclassified images to see if there were many representatives of a certain color or digit, but it doesn't seem to be the case either. In any case, after reading Keras' documentation and because of the fact that `Conv2D` forces you to pass it a 2-dimensional `kernel_size` that I imagine thus operates on all channels of the input image, the model shouldn't be taking color into account for classification here.

Am I missing something here?

Please let me know if you need any further information.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the last part of the model there is a relu activation then a softmax. It should just be a softmax (remove that relu). And otherwise, you don’t have nonlinearities between your conv blocks. You should probably add some.

Comment: @jakub ah indeed it was the relu + softmax, this worked, thank you. Any idea why it still managed classify for basic MNIST though ?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but maybe the MNIST dataset is simple enough that the network was able to cope. I will expand my comment into an answer, so it might help others reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last part of the model includes a dense -> relu -> softmax. The relu activation should be removed. In addition, you might benefit from adding non-linearities (e.g., relu) in your convolutional blocks. Otherwise, the neural network will end up being a (big) linear function and will not work as well for non-linear data.

```py
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10))
model.add(keras.layers.Softmax())
```

---

It is interesting that the original model worked well on the MNIST dataset. I cannot say for sure why, but perhaps the MNIST dataset is simple enough that the model was able to cope. Also, the `relu -> softmax` would clamp negative values to 0, and maybe there were not many negative values.